# Использование System.IO>>StreamReader в ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net

Вопрос простой: как подключить System.IO?
Если в коде .cs мы могли прописать `using System.IO`, то в .aspx я бессилен
Что надо сделать чтобы использовать StreamReader в теге <%...%>?

Comment: WebForms engine:`<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>`, Razor engine:  `@using System.IO`

Comment: WebForms engine:<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>, Razor engine: @using System.IO
В Razor не требуется System.IO - оно уже есть там.

Comment: Простите, Igor, ваш совет не помог( StreamReader выдает ошибку

Comment: Умоляю! **Какую** ошибку "выдает" StreamReader?!

Comment: Компилятор сообщает, что его не знает класс StreamReader

Comment: Извиняюсь, сам дурак, не там написал <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>,

Comment: Теперь все работает